# Powershell Exchange command Looping not working

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I am working on my Office 365 Exchange instance with Powershell and am having trouble with a command that I know I've run successfully in the past. I have broken this command down into its sub pieces and run them all fine on their own but just cannot seem to make this ForEach loop work. What might I be missing here?

```
PS C:\Users\bsigrist> ForEach ($Mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox)) 
{ $cal = $Mailbox.alias+":\Calendar" Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal 
  -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails }

        At line:1 char:108
        + ... cal = $Mailbox.alias+":\Calendar" Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identi ...
        +                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Unexpected token 'Set-MailboxFolderPermission' in expression or statement.
            + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcep
           tion
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon after `":\Calendar"`

Answer (score 3):

`$cal = $Mailbox.alias+":\Calendar" Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $cal 
  -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails`

That is being sent as one Powershell command, but I think you actually want it to be two commands. The first command assigns a value to `$cal` and the second command runs `Set-MailboxFolderPermission`.

As longneck points out, you can put a semicolon to separate those commands. Also discussed in the following locations:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattn/2012/04/28/powershell-command-separator-is-and-not/

https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell